# Possible more than one slash?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Is it possible to use more than 1 slash ('/')?

Example:

```
Route::get('/y/xyz', function() {
    return "Hello";
});
```

In this case it does not work...if I use only 1 "/" it will work? Is there any solutions?

ERROR was: When I changed the chronology of Routes it would work -_-

Comment: Do you mean like `/y//xyz`? If so, for what reason?

Comment: Can you give a better example? I have lots of routes defined as `Route::any("one/two", ...)` that work just fine.

Comment: Route::get('/customers/show/{id}', 'Controller@show'); Thats a possible problem... :/

Comment: That Route looks fine... What kind of error are you getting? Just remember your controller function needs `{id}` as a parameter: `public function show($id){ ... }`

Comment: Route::get('/customers/create',  'CustomerController@create'); does not work, i dont know why...if i call Route::get('/create',  'CustomerController@create'); it works :/

Comment: Again, what error are you getting? "Does not work" doesn't really help me fix this issue... And are you using `URL::to("/customers/create")` or `Redirect::to("/customers/create")`?

Comment: I am not using URL::to('/...') or Redirect.. I get no error, but it does not work i see a blank page...

Comment: Then it is probably working and you're not telling your route to do anything. What is happening in `public function create()`?

Comment: echo "Hello", i also tried return "Hello"

Comment: Try `die("Hello");` and see if that does anything.

Comment: Result is -> blank page :/

Comment: Still eh? Do you mind posting your `routes.php` and `CustomerController.php` so I can debug? Just edit your post, don't post it into the comments section. I'm curious to see what's wrong with it.